# Simple regular expression, alternative start, alternative end

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have a little problem I'm trying to solve all day. I think it is simple, but I cannot figure out the answer. I use *scrapy* written in Python. I need to parse the producer name from some div content.

**The scheme of div is:**

```
<div id=info>...
<html tag, can be p,strong,span,etc>
     Producer(sometimes as Supplier): some code
</end tag>...
</div>
```

**I use the next code:**

```
l.add_xpath('producer_name', "//div[@class='info']", re=u'Producer:\s*(.*)\s?</p>')
```

Everything works fine until I found page where "Supplier" is written instead of "Producer" or different end tag.

So I tried something like:

```
l.add_xpath('producer_name', "//div[@class='info']", re=u'[Supplier|Producer]:\s*(.*)\s?[</p>|<br>|</span>|</strong>]')
```

The above code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need parentheses, not square brackets, in your regular expression, i.e.:

```
l.add_xpath('producer_name', "//div[@class='info']", re=u'(Supplier|Producer):\s*(.*)\s?(</p>|<br>|</span>|</strong>)')
```

Comment: I know that everything in parentheses is matching. So to get the producer_name value, I need to extract data from [1] element of array. 

It is possible to use that, I think, but i'm looking for general solution.

Comment: @user1763395, with the square brackets you are creating a character class, what is wrong, so this solution should help you. What do you mean with "I'm looking for general solution"?

Comment: [quote]What do you mean with "I'm looking for general solution"?[/quote]

I'm trying to expain))

    l.add_xpath('producer_name', "//div[@class='info']", re=u'(Supplier|Producer):\s*(.*)\s?(</p>|<br>|</span>|</strong>)')

Here we have 3 matches. Can I exclude (Supplier|Producer) and (</p>|<br>|</span>|</strong>) from matching? Maybe I can use some flag to do this?

I do not want to count or find the necessary key of array. I want only one match. This my interpretation is general solution for my spiders:)

Comment: I'm reading now about Positive lookbehind. Hope it will help me

Comment: (?<=(\bProducer\b|\bSupplier\b))(.*)(?=(</strong>|<br>))

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out my problem. I decided to do in such way:

```
sudo apt-get install python-django

from django.utils.html import strip_tags

producer_name_in = MapCompose(strip_tags,remove_entities)

desc = hxs.select("//div[@class='desc']").extract()[0]
    producer_name = re.search(u'(Producer|Supplier):(.*?)(<br>|</p>|</span>)', desc)
    if producer_name:
        l.add_value('producer_name', producer_name.group(2))
```